# Launching emacs with configured packages

Tags: package, require

Let's say I want to use elisp functions in a script .
I rely in my script on some library, `dash` which I require.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/emacs --script
(require 'dash)

(message (describe-variable 'load-path))
```

As is, I will get

```
$ ./loader.sh
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, dash
```

**What is the simplest way to make a set of packages accessible to an elisp environment used in a script** ?

PS : The equivalent for haskell, using nix, would be

```
#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i runghc -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages(p: with p; [type-level-sets])"
#! nix-shell -I nixpkgs=channel:nixos-18.03


{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Main where

import Data.Type.Set (Set(..), Proxy(..))

class Get a s where
  get :: Set s -> a

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Get a (a ': s) where
  get (Ext a _) = a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Get a s => Get a (b ': s) where
  get (Ext _ xs) = get xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let lst = Ext "hello" $ Ext 10 $ Empty
  putStrLn $ show $ get @String lst
```

Answer (score 1):

I have one answer with Nix, but I am curious as to how it is possible to do so without Nix

```
#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i "emacs --script"  -p "pkgs.emacsWithPackages(epkgs: (with epkgs.melpaPackages; [ dash ]))"
#! nix-shell -I nixpkgs=channel:nixos-18.03
(package-initialize)
(require 'dash)

(message "Hi")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the directory where `dash.el[c]` resides in your `load-path` value, before you `require` that library:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/YOUR/DIRECTORY/CONTAINING/DASH/")
(require 'dash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
(package-initialize)
```

or for more modern Emacsen you can use

```
(package-activate-all)
```

In either case, it needs to come before the `require`.

Comment: it does not seem to work unfortunately. If I ask `(message (describe-variable package-load-list))` in the script `$./loader.sh`, I get `Symbol’s value as variable is void: package-load-list`

Comment: Works for me with Emacs-25.1.  Your error description seems odd: how come you don't get an error during `package-initialize` (i.e. before getting to `package-load-list`) then?

Comment: The documentation for `package-initialize` mentions this variable, which is why I looked into its it "controls which packages to load" it says... I guess it has some "safety" mechanism if it's not defined. in the end, it does not seem to load anything https://gist.github.com/nrolland/7e4e38e160b0cfa32f522742707fab6e

Comment: with nix and your tip, I have one solution. thank you